# GigaByte B760 Gaming + Core i9 13900K + Kingston DDR5 Fury 5600 incompatible?

Tags: memory, motherboard

Bought these components:

- GigaByte B760 Gaming X AX
- Core i9 13900K
- Kingston DDR5 Fury 5600 2x 32GB
- Asus 12GB RTX 3060 Gaming
- be quite power supply
- be quiet water cooler
- 2 Samsung 990 Pro

Memory placed in slots A2 + B2.

When i assemble the parts and start the system the DRAM led on the motherboard lights up and there is no display.

When i place the memory only in slots B1 & B2 the system starts and gives a display. So when there is memory in slot A1 or A2 the DRAM led lights up red and there is no display.

I've replaced the memory and the motherboard, problem is exactly the same!

Any ideas on what is wrong here?

DRAM LIGHT:

[image]

Slots used:

[image]

Comment: According to the specifications of the motherboard it fully supports 32 GB 5600Mhz DDR5 modules. In fact it supports 48 GB single DIMM capacity. DDR5_A2 or DDR5_B2 should be used in a single memory module configuration.  I presume you are using the outmost slot(clostest to the 24-pin motherboard power connector) and the next nearest slot?

Comment: Slot A2 and B2 are used as recommended by the manual.
https://prnt.sc/PAVCOq6a6Gie

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't work.  The manual I looked at suggested A1 and A2 in order to have a full single channel.  This is confirmed by the fact everything work when you used  B1 and B2 (same channel).

Comment: the manual I looked at says A2 and B2 as the OP says. Not sure which revision board the OP has though

Comment: @Peps The next step is to place just one stick of RAM in slot A2. Does it boot? Then power down, move the RAM to slot B2. Does it boot?

Comment: @Yorik - Only one revision of the board exists, and I do mention, I am suggesting single channel not dual channel. But the image they provided doesn’t work at all even when I am not behind a proxy.

Comment: 1 slot in A2 does NOT BOOT - 1 slot in B2 DOES BOOT.  I also added the screenshots to the main question above.

Comment: Also 4X 32GB did NOT BOOT.

Comment: maybe try entering BIOS and disabling XMP (if possible) and then try slots 2&4 again

Comment: @Peps Seeing as the memory controller is in the CPU, it could be that that is where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks all for thinking along, I've sent everything back to the store, they are having a look at it. I'll keep you posted about the outcome.

Comment: @yorik "disabling XMP", I believe it was already.

Comment: The processor was broken. A replacement solved the issues.